# Pythonのmultiprocessing.poolが実行されない

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

並列処理をさせたくて公式ドキュメントを参考しようとしたところ、multiprocessingの序盤の例文で実行されず、行き詰まっています。
実行環境
OS:Windows10
CPU:corei-5-3337U
コア:2
プロセッサ:4
Python:3.7

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,freeze_support 

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    with Pool(4) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

デバックをしながら確認するとp.map()で停止してそのまま応答がありません。
同ページでWindowsはfreeze_support()を入れる必要性を解説しており、`__name__== '__main__'`直後に入れましたが、動作しませんでした。

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

は実行されました。

実際にやりたいことは1例目のようにリストを渡して並列で処理させたいです。
Windowsで並列処理させるためにはどのようにすればいいのでしょか
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 会社のパソコンで実行したところ処理されました。パソコンの問題のようです。原因がわかりましたら、再度投稿します。

Comment: Windows10, Python 3.6.4環境でためしてみたところ、期待通り `[1,4,9]` が出力されました。「デバッグをしながら確認」とありますが、これが原因ではないでしょうか？multiprocessingは文字通りマルチプロセスで処理されるため、デバッガでのトレースは難しい気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。結果的にはご指摘の通りデバッガに問題がありました。現在VisualStudio2019でデバッグしていて、VSを更新したら問題が解消しました。